# Pure HTML5 videoconference

Tags: html, html5-video

I want to make a single web application avoiding any flash code. This application must contain videoconference, and I want to implement it in pure HTML5. It is possible? I know about websockets, but don't know really if videoconference can be implemented through them with a relative performance (at least, 24fps + sound at a right resolution, minimum 640x480), and both endpoints being web apps (both endpoints should use browser).

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does Google Hangouts use?

Answer (score 1):

Anyone following up this question - on Feb 4th, 2013 they produced the solution with WEBRTC in Chrome and Firefox. For examples see https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/02/hello-chrome-its-firefox-calling/ or http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/ or https://code.google.com/p/sipservlets/wiki/HTML5WebRTCVideoApplication

Answer (score 0):

You can't really use HTML5 video for live streaming at the moment, and it doesn't have support for web cams yet.

Ericsson has modyfied a WebKit browser and is showing how this can be done with hopfully upcoming HTML5 Stream API. See [Beyond HTML5 - Implementing and stream management in WebKit](https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-conversational-voice-and-video-implemented-webkit-gtk)

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to capture web-cam images/microphone feed just through JavaScript (although [there are plug-ins which let you handle output through flash](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/)), so it would be necessary for you to have some kind of application/plug-in installed.
The speed part is just for the client to worry. I mean, web sockets will be as fast as the connection permits.
You should do some research about web workers, since they would be very useful for speeding up your application (you could have microphone interface, web-cam interface and UI all with their particular worker, thus never blocking the application or rendering it unresponsive).

EDIT: the aforementioned jQuery plug-in works through the use of `<canvas>`.

Answer (score 0):

As Jonas said, according to the situations now, we can't build video conference with HTML5.  There are many limitations with browsers also. As there is no common video codec supported by all browsers. And live-streaming is also properly supported by safari only(using HTML5 video tag). As per my experience we can't build live-streaming on windows with any browser properly.
But if you wanna get some information about live streaming see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

you can use this source to test your live-streaming examples

"http://xfunoonx.api.channel.livestream.com/3.0/playlist.m3u8"

This content will work only with safari on Mac.